How to restrict autocomplete suggestions to given state?
I have an address form and I'm using Google's Places Autocomplete (new) API to autocomplete the fields.
I have 3 fields:

country
administrative_area_level_1 (State / Province)
locality (City / Town)

If the user selects Alabama, I want to show localities for the state of Alabama only.

I know that:

I can restrict results to countries with regionCode.
I can use locationBias.

regionCode works great. If the user selects a country, I use it to filter the other fields. Unfortunately, it only works with countries.
locationBias has a max radius of 50,000 meters. This is not enough to cover an entire state. Also, it doesn't restrict anything, so results are returned from all over the world.
I tried to append the state name to the search input input += " Alabama", but this way the autocomplete isn't returning anything. *
NOTE: Alabama is just an example. I would like autocomplete to work with any state in any country. I would also like autocomplete to work for street_addresses inside a locality this way.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

* EDIT: here's a minimal reproducible example of why appending the state to the input is not working for me, as requested by @MrUpsidown. I'm trying to search for Huntsville, Alabama by inputting "Hunt" in the City / Town field, the call yields 0 results.
AutocompleteSuggestion.fetchAutocompleteSuggestions(
{
  includedPrimaryTypes: ["locality", "postal_town"],
  input: "Hunt" + " Alabama",
});

Although the libraries I use to access the API shouldn't make a difference, I'll mention I'm using the 
Maps JavaScript API and the visgl/react-google-maps libraries for completeness sake.

Use the Place Autocomplete Data API and append the state to the user input when sending the request.


I'm already using the Data API. As I said, appending the state to the input doesn't really work.
Yeah, user input. It's an optional field.


Then provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. Appending the state works fine for me.

Okay @MrUpsidown, I added a code example to my post.

In the new Autocomplete API you can use locationRestriction and that one is not limited to 50 km so you can do entire states (so long as they are roughly rectangular shapred).

@miguev, I'm using the new API, you linked to the old API, the new one is this one, where they say "The radius must be between 0.0 and 50000.0, inclusive.". Anyway, even if it's allowed, locationRestriction is not a great solution IMO. There's no way to tell what state has what radius and even if there was a way, the radius would still include cities outside the state.

Right, sorry about that, I meant to link the locationRestriction in Place Autocomplete (New). Happily, they are pretty much the same, both allow specifying a rectangle as big as the world.

Ah yes I see, you were talking about the rectangle, thanks @miguev.
It has the same problems as the circle though (except for the 50km limitation of course).

It seems like it's not possible. I've submitted a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/373290671.
It's unfortunate and maybe there's different API that solves this problem. I went with fetching the coordinates from Places Details (New) and using locationBias with the max radius of 50,000 meters. It's not perfect but it's better than nothing.
